# Limiting site access to Mobile Phones

Tags: web-services, mobile, mobile-website

We are thinking of limiting our site access to mobile phones for some user trials in which we want to enforce trial users to use Mobile Phones. From my limited research on user strings, there is no good way of doing this since different browsers identify themselves differently and we might inadvertently block out a few users.

What does the community think? Good idea? Bad idea?

Comment: User agents can be spoofed _very_ easily. Do you want to make it impossible for non-mobile browsers to see your site?

Comment: What kind of mobile phones are we talking about here?

Comment: We are mostly talking about non-smart but multimedia phone browsers, mostly symbian etc. But we do not want to discount someone trying an iPhone or an Android browser with it.

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is a good or bad idea depends on your goals.

You're right that UserAgent strings are easily spoofed so it's not at all reliable but does that really matter for your trials?

Is inadvertently blocking a few users (those with wrong or unrecognized UA strings) really relevant when, by design, your blocking out the vast majority of users (anyone using a desktop browser)?

Comment: Good point. I guess I just want to say to the user, "Hey try this in your mobile browser". It would be bad for him to answer "BUT I AM". That's my only concern.

Comment: One potential solution to that would be to have a "But I am..." link which sets a cookie allowing them to bypass the check in the future.